# I need to switch which one of my drives is the C drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, drivers, ssd

My current C drive is very small and keeps filling up, and has minimal excess space with windows 8.1 installed. So i purchased a new 250GB SSD, and I want to know how to make that my new C drive.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have two options:

1. Reinstall Windows on to the new drive. During installation, it will ask you what drive to install onto. This drive will become your new C: drive. All your old files will still be on the old drive, which should be accessible with a different drive letter. All your old profile settings (e.g., desktop backgroud, icons on the desktop, etc.) will not be transferred.
2. Copy your old drive to the new drive (not the files on the drive, but the drive data itself), and use a partition resizing tool to make the partition fill the entire drive. This is more complicated, and slightly risky (although not nearly as risky as it used to be, "back in my day" :-P ). If you don't know what a partition is, or how to boot into non-Windows O/Ses, then this probably isn't for you.

Comment: I am not smart enough to attempt the second one ^.^ , but I have tried to reinstall windows, whenever the computer boots up it bypasses the usb that i am trying to boot from. I have tried going into BIOS and changing the boot order, I have also opened the boot menu and tried to change it that way, neither worked. Also, i know that it is usb compatible, because I originally installed windows via usb. Along with this I am not sure where the drive it is downloaded on is. As far as I know, there are only two plugged in, a one TB non SSD, and a 250 GB SSD.

Comment: Usually, when you boot a computer, there's an option for a "one-time boot", where you should be able to select USB.  Also, as there is already a valid Windows installation available, it'll detect that and say something like "Press any key to boot from DVD" or similar; if you don't press a key within about 2-3 seconds, it'll just boot from the hard drive. Also, it'd probably be a good idea to physically cable the new drive as the first one, probably swapping it's position with the older drive.